# Failed to Load Viewstate Error after editing Gridview in ModalPopupExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate, modalpopupextender

I am getting the following error.

```
HttpStatusCode:500
Name:Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException
Message: Sys.WebForms.Page.RequestManagerServerErrorException
Failed to Load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being 
loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during 
the previous request.
```

The scenario is as follows I have a `Gridview` that is bound after a `DropDownList` is selected. Then you can click a row on the `Gridview` and a `ModalPopupExtender` pops up. There is another `GridView` in the popup. If I edit that `Gridview` and then exit the `ModalPopupExtender`, and then select a different value on the `DropDownList` which generates the original `Gridview` I get the error.

**DropDownList**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SearchCategoryDD" runat="server" DataSourceID="InductionCategoriesDS" DataTextField="CompentencyCategory" DataValueField="CompentencyCategoryID" AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBound="SearchCategoryDD_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SearchCategoryDD_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**Gridview when Databound with new data causes error**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="SkillsXXX"  OnRowDataBound="SkillsXXX_OnRowDataBound" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SelectLBXX" Visible="False" OnClick="SelectLBXX_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="EmployeeXXXXD"  Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                 </EditItemTemplate>
......
...
```

**ModalPopupExtender with Gridview**

```
<asp:Button ID="EditSupplierContactPopupBTN" runat="server" Text="" Style="visibility: hidden;" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="EditSupplierContactMPE" runat="server" CancelControlID="EditSupplierContactCancelBTN"
                TargetControlID="EditSupplierContactPopupBTN" PopupControlID="EditSupplierContactPanel" PopupDragHandleControlID="EditSupplierContactHeader"
                Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="EditSupplierContactPanel" runat="server" CssClass="PopupPNL" Style="display: none"> <!--  Style="display: none" -->
    <div class="PopupHeader" id="EditSupplierContactHeader">
        <div class="PopupControls">
            <asp:Button ID="EditSupplierContactCancelBTN" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </div>
            Edit Truck Driver
    </div>
    <div class="PopupBody">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
             <asp:GridView ID="Competancies2GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SkillsMatrixID"  Width="100%">
                  <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="SkillsMatrixID">
                          <EditItemTemplate>
                              <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SkillsMatrixID") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:LinkButton ID="EditSkillsMatrixLB" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SkillsMatrixID") %>' OnCommand="EditSkillsMatrixLB2_Command">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="SkillsMatrixIDHF" Value='<%# Bind("SkillsMatrixID") %>'/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="CompentencyCategory" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="CompentencyCategory">
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="CompentencyName" HeaderText="Compentency" SortExpression="CompentencyName">
                          </asp:BoundField>
        ...........
        ........
        .....
```

I have tried the loading the `Datatable` from `ViewState` in the `LoadViewState` method. I still get the error.

**LoadViewState**

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object earlierState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(earlierState);
    dataTable = (DataTable)ViewState["dataTable2"];
    SkillsMatrixGV.DataSource = dataTable;

    compentencyDataTable = (DataTable) ViewState["CompentencyDataTable2"];
    Competancies2GV.DataSource = compentencyDataTable;
    Competancies2GV.DataBind();
    ......
    ...
```

if I put `EnableViewState="false"` into the page or the `GridView` the error goes away but my `GridView` in the `ModalPopupExtender` does not update.